# Nodejs - ADAL package issue

Tags: node.js, adal

I am using adal-node package in my Nodejs app for authenticating against Azure AD.
URL: https://www.npmjs.org/package/adal-node

I am using acquireTokenWithAuthorizationCode method to get the token and it works fine.
When my auth code expires, I want to refresh my token using the below.
authenticationContext.acquireTokenWithRefreshToken(_tokenData.refreshToken, authdata.clientId, authdata.resource, callback).

But when I run this code, its giving me the below error.
"Get Token request returned http error: 400 and server response: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":**"AADSTS90014: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_secret or client_assertion'**

The method will not accept client secret as its argument, but still it complains that it needs a client secret.

Can you please help?

Thanks
Anil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the library does not support your scenario right now.  The function acquireTokenWithRefreshToken that you are using was intended for OAuth public clients that don't require a client secret, but your app is an OAuth confidential client which does.

I have filed the following issue in the GitHub repo to track the need to add a new method that would support your scenario.

https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-nodejs/issues/22

Comment: Hi Rich, Can I use acquireTokenWithClientCredentials method when my auth code expires instead of acquireTokenWithRefreshToken method? Will this work the same way to get the token again? What is the difference between these two methods?

Comment: acquireTokenWithClientCredentials is meant only to authenticate a server.  It doesn't take a refresh token parameter so it will not produce tokens that are associated with the user for which you got an auth code.  As a result, you will not have access to that users resources.